# Facebook Audience Network Ad Sdk dependency giving run time error in Android App

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, facebook-android-sdk

While adding below dependency in build.gradle

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+'
```

The run project is giving error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzf.class

App, build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xyz.abc"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
   multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.picasso/picasso/pom.properties'
    pickFirst 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.picasso/picasso/pom.xml'
}

}

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

What can be possible solution for it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Update Gradle and Android Studio to latest version and it starts working.

Comment: That didn't work for me. I have the exact same problem.

Comment: If you find other solution feel free to post it.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
compile('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.13.0') 
{
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
```